# Why pyrolysis of C6H10 doesn't give C5H10 + CH4

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, pyrolysis

In my book it's given pyrolysis of C6H14 gives C6H12 + H2 Or C4H8 + C2H6 Or C3H6+C2H4+ CH4 ( as it gives atleast one alkene) but there are other possible alkenes  as well such as C5H10.

Comment: They may not have listed all the products. Also a typo in the title, should be C6H14.

Comment: ["*My book*" is meaningless](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3862). [Please always cite your sources properly](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4294). Besides, what are the conditions? Why the compound from the title doesn't match the one from the body? Is it a branched alkane (which one?), their mix or just *n*-hexane?

Comment: Yeah it's C6H14 ! Thnx for the ans.. And I wrote my book because there is no name of that book it is a question bank given by our school and we have to do particular questions after every class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed $\ce{C5H_{10}}$, specifically pent-1-ene, [has been documented[1]](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/kin.550190202):

> The pyrolysis of n-hexane has been investigated in the ranges 723–823 K and 10–100 Torr at up to 3% decomposition. The reaction is homogeneous and free from the self-inhibition by olefin products observed for several other alkanes. The products of the reaction are hydrogen, methane, ethane, ethene, propene, but-1-ene, and pent-1-ene, with smaller amounts of propane.

Most likely, the book simply did not list the products exhaustively.

**Reference**

1.
Freddy E. Imbert, Roger M. Marshall. "The mechanism and rate parameters for the pyrolysis of n-hexane in the range 723–823 K". *International Journal of Chemical Kinetics* **19** (2), 81-103. https://doi.org/10.1002/kin.550190202